# CSS Grid-gap not working on mobile

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I'm using CSS grid for my layout, and testing it in Chrome and Firefox everything works great. I have a 4 column layout with both row- and column-gaps, which at certain media query breakpoints turns into 2 columns, and later 1 column. This works like a charm. I tried testing my page on my phone, and everything seems to work, except for my grid-gaps, which is just ignored completely, and there is no gap. Then i tried testing my page in Edge, and here it seems that not a single grid property is working. Not even the basic layout of it. Any ideas why this is? I thought grid was fully supported at this point?

Comment: CSS Grid support is only available in the latest browser versions - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid
Depending on which phone/browser you are using it may be that it doesn't yet support grid, or you aren't adding vendor prefixes (-ms, -webkit, -moz).

Answer (score 0):

Edge has issues itself, not all devices universally support. Edge [probably still working](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/gridupdate/?q=grid%20update) around. Honestly making 100% fool proof with CSS very difficult for complicated layouts in real life.

You can look at [this jQuery for flawless grid](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height-demo/) on almost all devices in case your need is immediate for production purpose. jQuery projects has a basic advantage that users can report bug, test develop.